# How to store large data in Amazon EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

as part of a architecture project, we have to use Amazon Web Service, and particularly EC2. Our project is to store data about tennis games and total description of a point (forehand, volley, passing etc).
Thus at the end of a game, we'll have a data name "game" which will contains all data about the game.
Our datas will be accessed by complex requests. We choose to store data in non relational database.
In our architecure, which solution is convenient and why, to store datas? AmazonDB ? DynamoDB ? or S3?
I know that DynamoDB can store only datas < 64 kb, but it seems it's usually use in association with S3, but I can't see how...

**EDIT:**
We would like to use a distributed database, because our datas wil growth fastly, and we would like to have the possibility to add a new server which will contain a part of the database to handle high traffic.
Could we just install Hadoop on our instances?

Comment: This is a bit too broad of a question and also probably largely opinion based.  Without knowing much more about the application's data model and data access patterns, it would be impossible to give a reasonable answer here.

Comment: Item sizes can be 400 KB in DynamoDB. And I'm going to agree with Mark that this is too broad of a question and sounds like an [XY question problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want a No SQL DB? If you're using EC2 you could just mount a local Mongo DB server in your instance and access the data. Otherwise you could use DynamoDB, which is a managed NoSQL engine from AWS.

If you go through the SQL path you could also have a local MySQL or PostgreSQL server running on your EC2 instance, or launch an RDS instance your DB. The second option is more expensive, though.

S3 is not an option, since it is (almost) a unidirectional index; you can't sort or search for data.